# Spark streaming job on yarn keeps terminating after a few hours

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have a spark streaming job that consumes a kafka topic and writes to a database. I submitted the job to yarn with the following parameters:

```
spark-submit \
--jars mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0.jar,mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar,spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.5.jar \
--driver-class-path mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0.jar:mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.5.jar \
--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0.jar:mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.5.jar \
--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath=mongo-spark-connector_2.11-2.4.0.jar:mongo-java-driver-3.11.0.jar:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.4.5.jar \
--class com.example.StreamingApp \
--driver-memory 2g \
--num-executors 6 --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 3g \
--conf spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled=true \
--conf spark.streaming.backpressure.pid.minRate=10 \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=4 \
--conf spark.yarn.am.attemptFailuresValidityInterval=1h \
--conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=16 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.failuresValidityInterval=1h \
--conf spark.task.maxFailures=8 \
--queue users.adminuser \
--conf spark.speculation=true \
StreamingApp-2-4.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

But it terminates after a few hours with the following message on the terminal:

```
21/02/14 04:05:14 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/02/14 04:05:14 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Attempt recovered after RM restart
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: root.users.adminuser
     start time: 1613260105314
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: https://XXXXXXXXXx:8090/proxy/application_1613217899387_6697/
     user: adminuser
21/02/14 04:05:15 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/02/14 04:05:16 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/02/14 04:05:17 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/02/14 04:05:18 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/02/14 04:05:19 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: ACCEPTED)
21/02/14 04:05:20 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1613217899387_6697 (state: FINISHED)
21/02/14 04:05:20 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Attempt recovered after RM restartDue to executor failures all available nodes are blacklisted
     ApplicationMaster host: XXXXXXXXXx
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 41848
     queue: root.users.adminuser
     start time: 1613260105314
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: https://XXXXXXXXXx:8090/proxy/application_1613217899387_6697/
     user: adminuser
21/02/14 04:05:20 ERROR yarn.Client: Application diagnostics message: Attempt recovered after RM restartDue to executor failures all available nodes are blacklisted
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1613217899387_6697 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1155)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1603)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:851)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
21/02/14 04:05:20 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/02/14 04:05:20 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-e51d75e7-f19b-4f2f-8d46-b91b1af064b3
21/02/14 04:05:20 INFO util.ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-16d23c16-30f5-4ab7-95b2-4ac4ad584905
```

I've relaunched a few times, but the same thing keeps happening.

Spark version is `2.4.0-cdh6.2.1`, ResourceManager version is `3.0.0-cdh6.2.1`